# App crashes after implementing onClickListener

Tags: android, button, onclick

I just implemented the onClickListener. The App should switch between two layouts. On each layout there is one button. After touching the button the Layout should change.

I searched trough various tutorials and documentary, my code should be correct, I simply don't see the error. Eclipse also says the code is ok.

```
    package ralationship.v1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RelationshipActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button OptionsButton;
    private Button SaveButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SaveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        OptionsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOptions);
        OptionsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        SaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == (R.id.btnOptions)){
            setContentView(R.layout.options);
        }else if (v.getId() == (R.id.btnSave)){
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

    }

}
```

Does anyone find an error?

//EDIT:

Here is the LogCat Report:

```
01-26 15:47:29.273: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2549K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 67ms
01-26 15:47:29.453: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
01-26 15:47:29.462: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ralationship.v1/ralationship.v1.RelationshipActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at ralationship.v1.RelationshipActivity.onCreate(RelationshipActivity.java:22)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-26 15:47:29.473: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
01-26 15:47:33.633: I/Process(336): Sending signal. PID: 336 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `saveButton` is in the `R.layout.options` layout? If so, it is not available to be found when your activity is first created, as you only have the content from `R.layout.main`. You should instead put the lines

```
SaveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

inside the `onClickListener`, after you have changed the layout with `setContentLayout()` to the correct layout.

Answer (score 1):

if the options button is in the options xml than you have to inflate that manually. When you call setContentView and assign a layout xml you can then automatically inflate from what is on that specific xml. If you need to inflate anything else you have to use a layoutInflater
context.getSystemService(context.layoutInflaterservice)

basically dont instantiate the options button until you set the content view to it